# Azure role assignments to a AD group for a subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

Does Azure allow role assignment to a specific AD group for a specific subscription?

Comment: It sure does. Are you running into any issues with that?

Comment: I assume we talk about Azure Active Directory (AAD) groups, not Active Directory (AD) security groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a role to an AAD (security) group on subscription level. If using the Azure Portal, simply go to the "Access control (IAM)" tab of the desired subscription > Add > Add role assignment, enter the role and the name of the AAD group you want to assign.

[image]